# Can single conducting straight wire can radiate EM wave or we need two bend conducting wire similar to dipole antenna?

Tags: antenna

Actually I have read somewhere that there is no radiation if wire is straight. If it is true then why people are explaining antenna radiation with straight wire diagram?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit why you think that a straight wire cannot radiate? Can you provide the source where such a claim is made? For the record, a straight wire can radiate just fine.

Comment: For the second record: it is very, very difficult to make any active electronic circuit NOT radiate through any form or shape of wire.

Comment: Vladimir Cravero, if single wire can radiate then why we don't us single wire as antenna. and why dipole is known as very basic antenna instead of single wire?

Comment: I used to use single longwire antennas all the time, when I had the real estate.  Heck, a wet piece of spaghetti will work as an antenna; it might be tough to match, and not be efficient, but it can work.

Comment: *"I have read somewhere ..."* is not the basis for a good question. Without some sort of context, the statement is blatantly false, and therefore the question makes no sense as it stands. Can you provide a specific citation?

Comment: @Prerna Most cars (at least in the UK) until not that many years ago had a single (stiff) wire antenna for receiving AM/FM radio. See [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-the-high-radio-antennas-that-used-to-be-on-cars).

Answer (score 3):

Monopole antennas are single wire antennas and are basically half a dipole antenna. They rely on a ground to most effectively radiate (like a dipole) but can still radiate without a ground. Think also about transistor radios tuned to FM - they use a telescopic antenna that is a monopole with a less than ideal earth plane.

If a wire is passing current there is a magnetic field distributed around it. If there is an associated driving voltage (to produce the current) then there will also be a distributed electric field surrounding it.

Electric and magnetic fields are the two components that combine to make a radiating EM field so a wire *can* radiate. It may not radiate effectively at a lot of frequencies but can do so very effectively if the wavelength of the signal is proportioned to the dimensions of the wire.